# c# - cannot implicitly convert type void

Tags: c#

I have the following form which gives me the error that I cannot implicitly convert type void to HomeInventory2.Domain.CreateInventory...

my form

```
namespace HomeInventory2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateInventory create = new CreateInventory();
            create.ItemAmount = textBoxAmount.Text;
            create.ItemCategory = textBoxCategories.Text;
            create.ItemProperties = textBoxValue.Text;
            create.ItemValue = textBoxValue.Text;

            InventoryMngr invtryMngr = new InventoryMngr();
            CreateInventory creating = invtryMngr.Create(create);
        }
    }
}
```

and the createinventory file it is referencing

```
namespace HomeInventory2.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CreateInventory
    {
        private string itemCategory;
        public String ItemCategory
        {
            set { itemCategory = value; }
            get { return itemCategory; }
        }

        private string itemProperties;
        public String ItemProperties
        {
            set { itemProperties = value; }
            get { return itemProperties; }
        }

        private string itemAmount;
        public String ItemAmount
        {
            set { itemAmount = value; }
            get { return itemAmount; }
        }

        private string itemValue;
        public String ItemValue
        {
            set { itemValue = value; }
            get { return itemValue; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the exception?  It probably _really_ shouldn't be happening on `new CreateInventory();`, but we don't know what `invtryMngr.Create(create);` is.  Can you show the method signature for that?  If it's returning a `void` then that's your answer.

Comment: Post the code for `InventoryMngr`.  More information on your exception would be nice, such as what line it is breaking on.  Help us help you.

Comment: Whats the return type of InventoryMngr.Create ?

Comment: This is the line that gives you an Error.. Google on how to Create Constructors in C# 
CreateInventory creating = invtryMngr.Create(create);
you can't return Void

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing:

`CreateInventory creating = invtryMngr.Create(create);`

Why not just:

`invtryMngr.Create(create);`

Cause what you're doing is creating another `CreateInventory` that, judging by your code posted, doesn't need to be there.  And this is what is giving you the error, because `invtryMngr.Create()` returns void, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're calling a void method in `invtryMngr.Create(create);` so the compiler is telling you that since the method doesn't return anything, you cannot assign that to the `creating` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The line which gives you the error is:

```
CreateInventory creating = invtryMngr.Create(create);
```

Infact I think that `invtryMngr.Create(create)` didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

As other have pointed out already, the line `invtryMngr.Create(create);` is probably causing the problem.

The `Create` method probably has a void return type

```
public void Create(CreateInventory create)
{
    ...
}
```

Either call it like this without assignement

```
invtryMngr.Create(create);
```

or change the method to

```
public CreateInventory Create(CreateInventory create)
{
    ...
    return createdInventory;
}
```